# Creating Openshift template app - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, openshift, openshift-3

I am trying to setup an Openshift application but it stays on build "pending" forever. 
I noticed that no images were added to the imagestream.

I followed all the steps on this [link](https://docs.openshift.com/online/getting_started/basic_walkthrough.html) but it didn´t work. Can someone help me identify what is missing?

Comment: What OpenShift cluster are you using? Minishift? One you installed yourself? OpenShift Online? What do you get when you run ``oc get events``? Any errors?

Comment: I am using Openshift Online. I tested the same workflow on an instance of Openshift Origin on my local environment and it worked. No luck on Openshift online. The only error I got was:

`Error from server (BadRequest): unable to wait for build to run: timed out waiting for the condition`

Comment: Which OpenShift Online cluster? There is more than one.

Comment: `console.starter-ca-central-1.openshift.com`

I decided to try some changes and use the project creation UI. I change the Node version from 8 to 6.
Now everything works just fine. I have no idea why I needed to change the version but this was the only difference between my local environment and my online environment

Comment: Also I learned that the deployment cycle has some bugs and sometimes your deployment gets stuck in pending. Is that correct? Do you know any solutions or workarounds for this issue?

Comment: It may be transient issues with the cluster. They went through an upgrade a week ago, so maybe there is some lingering issues related to that.

Comment: Okay I will have to wait and see then. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Please follow along on the Starter StatusPage: https://status.starter.openshift.com/incidents/3bbcmkd91dp0